# Get operation name in Message Inspector?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, action

Im using the `IClientMessageInspector` to log in/out messages but the problem is that I can´t find how to get the operation name from `AfterReceivedReply` and `BeforeSendRequest`.

I have tested the following :

```
if ((action = reply.Headers.Action.Split('/').LastOrDefault()) != null)
{
   callInformation.Action = action;
   callInformation.Address = reply.Headers.Action.Replace(action, "");
}
```

This works fine in `BeforeSendRequest` but in the `AfterReveivedReply` it returns something different, often with the *"Response"* on the end?

**How do I only get the operation name in those methods?**

Say, that my operation is named `MyOperation` and a `OperationContract` attribute states the `action = "MyOpeation"` (wrong spelling). This result of this is that `MyOpeation` will be extracted in `BeforeSendRequest` while the `AfterReceiveReply` will return `MyOperationResponse`.

So the `BeforeSendRequest` will extract the stated action in the attribute and the `AfterReceiveReply` will extract the real operation name but with the add of *"Response"* on the end?

Its important to be able to match the in/out messages and the only way of doing this as I see it is to match the operation names but if that is not possible then I do not see a good solution to this?

I have seen solution when using OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action but the OperationContect.Current is null when doing this on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I assume you want to match In/Out messages by any means - the framework provides for this:

In the implementation of [`IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest.aspx) you can return a unique `correlationState` which in turn allows you to relate the reply message in your implementation of [`IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.afterreceivereply.aspx) since the Framework will call your implementation with it as the second parameter.

**EDIT - as per comments below:**

IF you really need to get the name of the operation/method called you could do this is by implementing [`IClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter.serializerequest.aspx) OR [`IParameterInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx) - this will allow you to to record which method with which parameters have been called and what Message object the framework created for it.

Comment: But is it not possible to get a clean operation name?

Comment: @SnowJim AFAIK yes it is possible but rather complicated (you would need to implement other/additional `Inspector` interfaces)... since you wrote that your main motivation is to match In/Out I provided a solution which works based on your existing implementation...

Comment: Could you pleas give me a tips about these interfaces that I whould need?

Comment: @SnowJim One way you could do this is by implementing [`IClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter.serializerequest.aspx) OR [`IParameterInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx) - this will allow you to to record which method with which parameters have been called and what Message object the framework created for it.